# how do i get a button-click event to also change the background color of a label box to red?

Tags: cocoa

I've worked with VB.NET in the past.

VB.NET is an object oriented language, but since all view objects have a name, you can double-click on (ButtonX) and it will take you to where you write your code for the (ButtonX-clicked) event .. if you want to set the background color of (LabelX) you just write 
(LabelX.backgroundcolor = red).

I am now trying to learn how to write programs for OS X.

I've gotten to the point where I can click a button and display `"hello"` in a label, but I don't know where to go from there.

How do I get a button click event to also change the background color of a label box to red?

Can you provide sample code?

I do not have a good understanding of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do some reading on Cocoa event handling. It could provide some basic knowledge on how to deal with object events in OS X.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html

Comment: hi kdmurray .. thanks for the response.
i have read a couple of cocoa books, but even with 52 years of programming, i just can't grasp class concepts .. i am hoping i can learn to write apple apps by building up a library of (put this line of code here to accomplish this task) .. that is how i have learned other languages.

Comment: I wonder if trying C# or Java, even for just a short while, might provide a bit of a bridge between VB and Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the code you need is not that different in structure from what you know from VB.NET.

You say you already have the code to put "Hello" into the label, so you must have a reference to the label stored in a variable of type `NSTextField *`, let's say you've called this `myLabel`. Lookup `NSTextField` and you will see it has two methods `backgroundColor` and `setBackgroundColor:` - and any pair of methods following this naming pattern can be referenced as a *property*. So to set the background color of your label all you need is:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor];
```

which should not look too unusual to a VB.NET person.

If you don't wish to use the property syntax you can instead write:

```
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[NSColor red]];
```

and you will see this a lot in code as the property syntax is fairly new in Objective-C. HTH.

Comment: hi crd

thanks for the help

in the (AppDeligate.h) section I put a line
   @property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *myLabel;
is that what you mean by (reference to the label)?

there is also a line
   -(IBAction)ButtonX:(id)sender;

in the (AppDeligate.m) section, under 
   -(IBAction)ButtonX:(id)sender {
I put your line 
   _myLabel.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor];
the program ran but did not color the label box.

the same for the line 
   [_myLabel setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];

jerry

Comment: The `@property` is OK, but it sounds like you have not connected it in IB. But surely you already have a reference to the label as you say you set its text to "Hello" - to do that you need a reference! When referencing the property you should use `self.myLabel` and not `_myLabel` - the latter references the variable behind the property and not the property itself (it may seem to work for now, but it can break things and you should get in the habit of using the property).

Comment: how do i reference a label (give it a name) so that i can refer to it in my code ?

i can do about anything in cobol, fortran, old machine language, old c, old pascal, and vb.net .. i just seem to have a mental block regarding classes.

i live in missouri and the tornados are getting close (again).

Comment: @jerrygentry - How did you set the text to "Hello", to do that you must have a reference to the label. However your `@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *myLabel;` is the correct way to *declare* the outlet. Then in IB you need to *connect* the outlet; you do that by click and drag, just as you connected your `IBAction` for the button. If you are stuck on this you need to read Apple's IB documentation.

Comment: thanks CRD .. 
  
i have read books .. teach yourself xcode in 24 hours .. and .. programming in objective-c .. 
  
i will do some more reading on cocoa .. 
  
the windows program i was asked to convert to apple is my 65,000 line Vb.Net program .. microlog .. 
  
you can see what the program does by clicking the (other-program-screens) link on my website .. 
  
www.wa0h.com .. (0) is the number zero .. 

thanks for your patience